# Include adjacent cells when copying matched values to other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that compares values in cells in two different sheets on a google spreadsheet. It can successfully match find the matches and copy them to a 3rd sheet. However, I want to expand the selection to the column left of the matches and copy over both the matches and adjacent cells.

For clarification: Spreadsheet 1 has emails and majors, spreadsheet 2 has majors under what college they belong to. I am matching the majors so I can get the emails of only the people in a specific college. Right now all it copies are the cells with the major, but I would like it to copy the cells with the email as well (which are one column to the left).

```
function match_CoE() {
  //Set variables for active spreadsheet, input data, comparitive data, and finalized match input.
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var input = sh.getSheetByName('AOP 2018-2019').getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  var values = sh.getSheetByName('Major-College-Conversion').getRange("A72:A75").getValues();
  var output = sh.getSheetByName('College of Education Contacts');
  var match = [];

  //Compare Input to Pre-determined values for matches
  for (i in input){
    var setInput = input[i][0];
    var exists = false;

    for (j in values){
      var setValues = values[j][0];
      if (setValues == setInput){
        exists = true;
        break;
      }
    } // end for j
    if (exists == true){
        match.push([setInput])
    }
  }//end for i

  //Copy matching values to new sheet.
  output.getRange(1, 1, match.length, 1).setValues(match);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you declare `var mail = sh.getSheetByName('AOP 2018-2019').getRange("D1:D").getValues();`, push its value into another array when `exist == true`, and populate its value in `output` the same way you do with `match` ?

Comment: @HaPhan I'm unsure what you mean? Wouldn't that just copy over all the data from the column?

Comment: Expand your obtained range (e.g. B2:B -> A2:B), and use `Array#filter`. Note that right now you have a nested loop - for every element of `input`, you rescan potentially all of `values`. See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286994/9337071), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935477/9337071), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519839/9337071) for examples that optimize similar tasks. Once you've edited your code to attempt to solve your task, I or others will be happy to help fix the code you've written (vs. just doing it all for you).

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch and @HaPhan! I was able to figure it out, you guys were of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expanded my search range to include the email list and shifted the set data I was matching against over a row. Then changed the setInput variable in the loop to +1 narrowing the search to just the majors and adding a second variable (setInputFina) to return just the emails I was able to generate the list!

```
function match_CoE() {
  //Set variables for active spreadsheet, input data, comparitive data, and finalized match input.
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var input = sh.getSheetByName('AOP 2018-2019').getRange("B1:C").getValues();
  var values = sh.getSheetByName('Major-College-Conversion').getRange("A72:B75").getValues();
  var output = sh.getSheetByName('College of Education Contacts');
  var match = [];

  //Compare Input to Pre-determined values for matches
  for (i in input){
    var setInput = input[i][+1];
    var setInputFinal = input[i][0];
    var exists = false;

    for (j in values){
      var setValues = values[j][+1];
      if (setValues == setInput){
        exists = true;
        break;
      }
    } // end for j
    if (exists == true){
        match.push([setInputFinal])
    }
  }//end for i

  //Copy matching values to new sheet.
  output.getRange(1, 1, match.length, 1).setValues(match);
}

function copySet_CoE() {

}
```